# polyserve cannot serve the app

Tags: polymer, web-development-server, polymer-cli

Node v8.11
NPM  v5.6

Whenever I try to call polymer serve an error occurs telling that server failed to start and no available ports, which is wrong! most of the ports are available.

```
$ polymer serve
ERROR: Server failed to start: Error: No available ports. Ports tried: [8081,8000,8001,8003,8031,2000,2001,2020,2109,2222,2310,3000,3001,3030,3210,3333,4000,4001,4040,4321,4502,4503,4567,5000,5001,5050,5432,6000,6001,6060,6666,6543,7000,7070,7774,7777,8765,8777,8888,9000,9001,9080,9090,9876,9877,9999,49221,55001]
    at /Users/nabed/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:380:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/nabed/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:17:58)
    at <anonymous>
error:   cli runtime exception: Error: Error: No available ports. Ports tried: [8081,8000,8001,8003,8031,2000,2001,2020,2109,2222,2310,3000,3001,3030,3210,3333,4000,4001,4040,4321,4502,4503,4567,5000,5001,5050,5432,6000,6001,6060,6666,6543,7000,7070,7774,7777,8765,8777,8888,9000,9001,9080,9090,9876,9877,9999,49221,55001]
error:   Error: Error: No available ports. Ports tried: [8081,8000,8001,8003,8031,2000,2001,2020,2109,2222,2310,3000,3001,3030,3210,3333,4000,4001,4040,4321,4502,4503,4567,5000,5001,5050,5432,6000,6001,6060,6666,6543,7000,7070,7774,7777,8765,8777,8888,9000,9001,9080,9090,9876,9877,9999,49221,55001]
    at /Users/nabed/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:91:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/Users/nabed/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:18:65)
    at <anonymous>
```

here is a `--verbose` err log text http://freetexthost.com/2sjgr45yx5
I am on mac, I installed node via package installer form there website

Comment: Try running with `--verbose` to see if any useful log messages appear that could help troubleshoot.

Comment: @tony19 It worked then it is back to throw (no available ports) error again, I made the edit to the post by attaching a link holds --verbose output

Comment: Try `polymer serve --hostname 0.0.0.0` or replace `0.0.0.0` with an IP that is available on the machine.

Comment: @synk That worked thanks, but curious to know why it struggles on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @synk said on the comment:

> polymer serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 or replace 0.0.0.0 with an IP
>   that is available on the machine