# web-component-tester cannot bind to port

Tags: docker, polymer, wct

I have a docker setup with following containers:

1. selenium-hub
2. selenium-firefox
3. selenium-chrome
4. spring boot app
5. node/java service for wct tests

All these containers are defined via docker-compose.
The node/java service is created as follows (extract from docker-compose):

```
  wct:
    build:
      context: ./app/src/main/webapp
      args:
        ARTIFACTORY: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}
    image: wct
    container_name: wct
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - selenium-chrome
      - selenium-firefox
      - webapp
```

The wct tests are run using:

```
docker-compose run -d --name wct-run wct npm run test
```

And the wct.conf.js looks like following:

```js
const seleniumGridAddress = process.env.bamboo_selenium_grid_address || 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub';
const hostname = process.env.FQDN || 'wct';

module.exports = {
  activeBrowsers: [{
    browserName: "chrome",
    url: seleniumGridAddress
  }, {
    browserName: "firefox",
    url: seleniumGridAddress
  }],
  webserver: {
    hostname: hostname
  },
  plugins: {
    local: false,
    sauce: false,
  }
}
```

The testrun fails with this stacktrace:

```
ERROR: Server failed to start: Error: No available ports. Ports tried: [8081,8000,8001,8003,8031,2000,2001,2020,2109,2222,2310,3000,3001,3030,3210,3333,4000,4001,4040,4321,4502,4503,4567,5000,5001,5050,5432,6000,6001,6060,6666,6543,7000,7070,7774,7777,8765,8777,8888,9000,9001,9080,9090,9876,9877,9999,49221,55001]
at /app/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:384:15
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:17:58)
```

I tried to fix it as per: [polyserve cannot serve the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612925/polyserve-cannot-serve-the-app) but without success.
I also tried setting `hostname`to `wct` as this is the known hostname for the container inside the docker network, but it shows the same error.

I really do not know what to do next.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you already have "containers" running. Did you stop them? make sure if any containers running and listening on same ports. docker container ls.

Comment: I double checked and all containers are stopped before I perform the `docker-compose run`command.

Comment: If that is the case, check who is consuming "host ports". It seems some one already consuming the host ports.

Comment: I do not think it is plausible that +20 ports are occupied inside a container. I think it is more a permissions issue or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the hostname was incorrect, so WCT was unable to bind to an unknown hostname.